# Understanding electron behavior in extreme laser

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, laser, scattering

https://phys.org/news/2017-06-billion-suns-world-brightest-laser.html

Just read this. Interesting behavior described with regard to how electrons change behavior after being placed in the beam of an extreme laser.

I was wondering how it's possible that the brightness increases, and how the ejected photon's absorbs all the scattered light. Is this consistent with the laws of conservation? What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is one of science journalism's finer efforts.

[Thomson scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering) of light from an electron is well described using classical electrodynamics. Essentially the electric field makes the electron oscillate and the oscillating electron reradiates an EM field at the same frequency as the incoming wave.

Multiphoton Thomson scattering, the subject of this paper, is also well described by classical electrodynamics and differs only in that light is now reradiated not only at the frequency of the incoming light but at multiples of the frequency. This is a well known phenomenon. The earliest reference I have found is Sengupta, N. D., 1949, Bull. Math. Soc. (Calcutta) 41, 187 so that's 69 years ago (disclaimer: I can't find a copy of this paper so I know only that it was cited as describing multiphoton Thompson scattering).

In the article you cite I find phrases such as:

> As it would under normal conditions, the electron also ejected its own photon, which was jarred loose by the energy of the incoming photons.

which seems to me largely meaningless. Anyhow I don't think there is anything fundamentally interesting in the paper though it's a nice techinical demonstration of the effect.